# Increase Xcode IDE font size

Tags: xcode, xcode9

This question is about increasing the font size of Xcode IDE itself (I know how to increase the font size of editor). Searched the internet but couldn't find a single working solution.

Does anyone know any hack to get it done?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -3):

This is set in the OS system preferences.

System Preferences > Display > Display Tab > Resolution > Select Scaled and choose Larger text...

[image: screenResolution]

Comment: this will scale screen display and impact overall. isn't it?

Comment: My monitor is already set to this. I have a 4K monitor but the current effective resolution is 1440p. With this also, Xcode fonts are quite small. I don't want to go below 1440p resolution just to fix Xcode's crappy fonts.

Answer (score -4):

Go to `XcodePreferences` from menu and then `Fonts`. Below images is for ref:

[image]

**Change  font from here:**

[image]

Comment: Which one to increases the Xcode font (I'm not looking for increasing editor font size)?

Comment: this all belongs to editor fonts. You can refer colors with respect to code. like Comments is for all comments you write in codes. and Plain text is coding text, Project ClassNames corresponds to classNames. you need to select either one by one or select all and change font. Here it is "SF Mono Regular". you change from that drop down.

Comment: Please read my question, I'm not asking to change code editor font size.